# Using when exists in case statement issue

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want the 'color' set to 'gold' if the member and member_levl from tabC exists in the premium_tab. Now, it does work if I only have 1 record in the premium_tab. But when I have multiple records in the premium_tab, it sets all their 'color' values to null ('') regardless if the member exists or not in tabC. Not sure what the issue is and how to fix this?

```
begin for rec in premium_tab
 loop for rec1 in default_tab
  loop insert into attire_tab (outfit, outfit_val)
   values (rec1.outfit_code,
           case rec1.outfit_code when 'color' then (case when exists (select 'x' from tabC where member=rec.user and member_levl=rec.lvl)
                                                         then 'gold' else '' end)
                                 else 'other' end);
     end loop; end loop; end;
```

Comment: What's the relationship between `premium_tab` and `default_tab`? It would help if you posted some sample data and required output derived from that output.

Comment: I think you'd be better doing this as an INSERT SELECT rather than an RBAR operation

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @APC hey I posted the sample data and output. Thanks!

Comment: @GordonLinoff posted the sample data and outputs, thank you

Comment: @CaiusJard Hi thanks for the response and suggestion. I will try it out - but still curious on why this isn't working. Also, it's part of a larger script so ideally I'd like to still use cursors only because the other devs are using them to maintain readability

Comment: Cameo pants? Are those [the ones with a plastic codpiece](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZjAantupsA)? :)

Comment: @APC haha, I didn't even know what they were xD - anwyay, sorry I posted this question!! It does work, it was just bad data on my part :P

Comment: It'd be worth getting the other devs to come round to the idea of stopping using cursors; they're a) the devil and b) needed only in exceptional cases. The hard part is getting a human to stop thinking in a row-by-row way and start thinking in blocks of data. That was one of the hardest things about jumping from Oracle to SQLS for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a set based operation:

```
INSERT attire_tab(outfit,outfit_val)
SELECT  
  rec1.outfit_code, 
  case 
    when rec1.outfit_code = 'color' 
      case when tabc.member is not null then 'gold' else '' end
    else 'other'
  end
FROM
  premium_tab rec 
  CROSS JOIN
  default_tab rec1
  LEFT JOIN
  tabC
  ON
    tabc.member=rec.user and tabc.member_levl=rec.levl
```

Few benefits to this approach:

One that you are writing a select query (comment put the INSERT line during development)that essentially embodies the entire block of data you want to insert- it's easy to do in a query tool, it's read only, it can be run multiple times and tested, perfected without needing to do a "write sproc code, run sproc, select from table to check, wipe table back to start state, amend sproc, run sproc again"

Two, that the db query engine is free to optimise the query however it likes rather than having to run the query in the set of steps forced by the row-by-row nature of the sproc code. It's almost always better to avoid row by row operations in favour of blocks of data. If rec and rec1 have a thousand rows each, that exists query might feasibly be run a million times. If tabc only had 100 rows it would certainly be faster to do a join to the existing data to find the tiny fraction of rows that relate to a member, than to hit the table or its index a million times (a thousand repeats of a thousand lookups)

And a precautionary note; if the relationship between rec and tabc is m:m then the left join will cause a multiplying of the rows, known as a Cartesian product. Additional care would be needed to handle this case because the exists route only asks whether a rec has any one matching tabc row, but this route joins them up. I initially considered that a particular premium row would relate to only one member, hence the left join is safe to use